# customizing the wget or find similars

Tags: wget

I need to wget the whole page including the dropdown menu

Linux Ubuntu 16, I am trying to wget a whole page including the dropdown menu that's on the right side you can check the page here https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/

The dropdown menu I mean is that starts with blockchain then control then generating and their content and the content inside the choices inside them

I tried wget https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/

When I tried wget https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/ they were empty.
I need to include the whole page content including the clickable options inside it as long as they open inside the page and am afraid of copy-paste to word file as its sensitive lines that I need the original to be in the face of me in the case of this website got broken and archive org also what I expect is to download the whole page including all the content in the body that's clickable

Comment: Are the menus being generated with JavaScript? wget will only get you the page source.

Comment: maybe php or js not completely sure, is there's any similar solutions like wget?